# Server-Side and Time-Specific script execution

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, server, server-side

I have a list of dates in an array(for now we can say that the dates are sorted). I want to have a script execute when the date matches a date in the array. My issue is figuring how to make this work on its own. I would like to have a server somehow act like an alarm clock that can run a script for a scheduled date and time. If anyone could help with suggestions to make this work I would appreciate it.

`set date >>> if (currentDate == set date) >>> run script for the respective data`

Please ask if you need clarification.

Comment: A script to run on the server, one each of a bunch of dates? What language are you running on the server? Javascript? Does that mean node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this with parse is a class with a date attribute.  Create one object per date in your array of dates (they needn't be sorted).

Create a scheduled job that upon running, query's the class for the first date equal to the current date.  If one is found, do whatever you want to do when an alarm  is triggered.

So, something like...

```
Parse.Cloud.job("checkStatus", function(request, status) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var tomorrow = new Date(today);
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

    var query = new Parse.Query("MyAlarmClass");
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('theDateAttribute', today);
    query.lessThan('theDateAttribute', tomorrow);
    return query.first().then(function(anAlarm) {
        if (anAlarm) {
            // do whatever should be done on the alarm
        } else {
           // do nothing
        }
    }).then(function() {
        status.success();
    }, function(error) {
        status.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

Schedule this to run at least twice per day (or faster than whatever resolution you need on the alarms).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad you found a way to make this work with a Parse Job.

Comment: Will this need to be run often or only once in order to get the scripts to execute close to when they are supposed to?

Comment: But I am concerned as to how long this will be running for because it seems like the job will running the whole day in this case.

Comment: The job is required to run in <10 seconds (otherwise will time out).  Running it daily means it will absorb <10 seconds/day of server time.

Comment: but if the server is running only when the some date meet the criteria i still need more parse requests for the remainder?